# Show that P is an L-projection iff $P^{*}$ is an M-projection

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I have started reading "M-ideals in Banach spaces and Banach algebras", but I stuck on the first page. It says that "there is an obvious duality between L- and M- projections:

- P is an L-projection on X iff $P^{*}$ is an M-projection on $X^{*}$
- P is an M-projection on X iff $P^{*}$ is an L-projection on $X^{*}$"
  ,

that is (as for the 1st sentence) :

$$ \forall_{x\in X}\Vert x\Vert=\Vert Px\Vert+\Vert x-Px\Vert\implies
\forall_{f\in X^{*}} \Vert f\Vert=max(\Vert P^*f\Vert,\Vert f-P^*f\Vert)
$$
I have tried but it is not so obvious for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be an $L$-projection. From

$$\lVert x\rVert = \lVert Px\rVert + \lVert x-Px\rVert$$

for all $x\in X$ it follows that $\lVert P\rVert \leqslant 1$ and $\lVert I-P\rVert \leqslant 1$, and hence

$$\lVert P^\ast f\rVert = \lVert f\circ P\rVert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert P\rVert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert,$$

and analogously $\lVert (I-P)^\ast f\rVert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert$ for all $f\in X^\ast$. Therefore $\lVert f\rVert \geqslant \max \left\{ \lVert P^\ast f\rVert, \lVert f - P^\ast f\rVert\right\}$. On the other hand,

$$\begin{align}
\lvert f(x)\rvert &= \lvert f(Px) + f(x-Px)\rvert\\
&\leqslant \lvert f(Px)\rvert + \lvert f((I-P)x)\rvert\\
&= \lvert f(P^2x)\rvert + \lvert f((I-P)^2x)\rvert\\
&= \lvert (P^\ast f)(Px)\rvert + \lvert ((I-P)^\ast f)((I-P)x)\rvert\\
&\leqslant \lVert P^\ast f\rVert\lVert Px\rVert + \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\lVert x-Px\rVert\\
&\leqslant \max\left\{ \lVert P^\ast f\rVert, \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right\}
\left(\lVert Px\rVert + \lVert x-Px\rVert\right)\\
&= \max\left\{ \lVert P^\ast f\rVert, \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right\} \lVert x\rVert,
\end{align}$$

whence $\lVert f\rVert \leqslant \max\left\{ \lVert P^\ast f\rVert, \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right\}$.

Together, we have $\lVert f\rVert = \max\left\{ \lVert P^\ast f\rVert, \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right\}$, so $P^\ast$ is an $M$-projection.

Let now $P$ be an $M$-projection. Since $f = P^\ast f + (f-P^\ast f)$, it follows that $\lVert f\rVert \leqslant \lVert P^\ast f\rVert + \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert$ for all $f\in X^\ast$. For the reverse inequality, let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, and choose $a,b\in X$ with $\lVert a\rVert\leqslant 1$, $\lVert b\rVert\leqslant 1$ and

$$(P^\ast f)(a) \geqslant (1-\varepsilon)\lVert P^\ast f\rVert,\quad ((I-P)^\ast f)(b) \geqslant (1-\varepsilon)\lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert.$$

Let $x = Pa + (I-P)b$. Then

$$\lVert x\rVert = \max \left\{ \lVert Px\rVert, \lVert x-Px\rVert\right\} = \max \left\{ \lVert Pa\rVert, \lVert (I-P)b\rVert\right\} \leqslant \max \{ \lVert a\rVert, \lvert b\rVert\} \leqslant 1,$$

and

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(Pa + (I-P)b)\\
&= f(Pa) + f((I-P)b)\\
&= (P^\ast f)(a) + ((I-P)^\ast f)(b)\\
&\geqslant (1-\varepsilon)\left(\lVert P^\ast f\rVert + \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right),
\end{align}$$

hence $\lVert f\rVert \geqslant (1-\varepsilon)\left(\lVert P^\ast f\rVert + \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert\right)$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\lVert f\rVert \geqslant \lVert P^\ast f\rVert + \lVert f-P^\ast f\rVert$. Together, we have equality, and $P^\ast$ is seen to be an $L$-projection.

For the implications in the other direction, note that if $P^\ast$ is an $L$- resp. $M$-projection, then by the above $P^{\ast\ast}$ is an $M$- resp. an $L$-projection, and since $P$ is the restriction of $P^{\ast\ast}$ to $X$, it follows that $P$ is an $M$- resp. an $L$-projection.

---

From a more systematic viewpoint, if $R$ and $K$ are the range and kernel of $P$ respectively, then $X$ is isomorphic to the direct product $R\times K$ via the map $\Phi \colon x \mapsto (Px, x-Px)$. Then

- $P$ is an $L$-projection if and only if $\Phi$ is an isometry when the product $R\times K$ is endowed with the sum norm, $\lVert (u,v)\rVert_1 = \lVert u\rVert + \lVert v\rVert$, and
- $P$ is an $M$-projection if and only if $\Phi$ is an isometry when the product $R\times K$ is endowed with the maximum norm, $\lVert (u,v)\rVert_\infty = \max \left\{ \lVert u\rVert, \lVert v\rVert\right\}$.

The correspondence between $L/M$-projections on $X$ and $M/L$-projections on $X^\ast$ then is a manifestation of the fact that the dual norm of the sum norm on $R\times K$ is the maximum norm on $R^\ast\times K^\ast$ and the dual norm of the maximum norm is the sum norm on $R^\ast \times K^\ast$.

Comment: Thanks, not so hard, but not so obvious either. There is an error in "Since $f = P^\ast f + (x-P^\ast f)$"- tried to edit it but it does not want to save. Could you maybe recommend some material with more basic approach on L-embedded spaces?

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed. Before you have the edit privilege [2000 rep], edits you suggest must be at least six [non-whitespace] characters, that's why it didn't accept your attempted fix. The reason for the character minimum on suggested edits is that the reviewers should not have to deal with too many trivial suggestions. In cases like this, that is of course inconvenient. One trick to get around the limit is to also make some not necessary but not bad changes, here you could for example have completed the abbreviated "resp." to reach the limit. But, there is still a risk that such suggestions ...

Comment: ... will be rejected as too minor. Commenting and waiting for the author to fix it can be the better alternative. I'm sorry, but I don't know any literature on L-embedded spaces at all, I have never worked in that area.